# R: Capturing Strike-Through Text Using RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-table, rselenium

I am using RSelenium to scrape data tables from a website. Iterated through many pages using a loop.

The code below, successfully scrapes the table in question (albeit looses UTFC formatting), however in some cases entries in the table have a "strike-through", in which case the code to ignores the strike through and acts is if it is not there.

Example:

[image] but records in R as [image]

Could anyone please help with how I may retain the strike through information when I scrape the table?

My code scraping table:

```
Data_table_html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
                                  read_html() %>%
                                  html_table(header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
```

I have spent hours on this, so any help or pointers would be immensely helpful,

Comment: Could you share the url or the part of the html code?

Comment: I would like to share the solution I found, below. In short identifying nodes in HTML which have html_attr as "style" does the trick:

saving <- html_nodes((remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]), xpath='your xpath') %>% 
                                  html_attr("style") %>% gsub("text-decoration:line-through;", "0", .) #%>%  html_table(fill=TRUE)

Comment: Good!! 
If you found the solution I suggest you to share below in the answers box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to share the solution I found, below. In short identifying nodes in HTML which have html_attr as "style" does the trick:

`saving <- html_nodes((remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]), xpath='your xpath') %>% html_attr("style") %>% gsub("text-decoration:line-through;", "0", .) #%>% html_table(fill=TRUE)`